# How do I get a post (page or CPT) ID from a title or slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, title

I've scoured the Codex, failed to get get_page_by_title() to work and am quite surprised that there doesn't seem to be a standard WP function for this task.

I need to get the ID of any given post/ cpt or page using either the slug of the post/ page title. Ideally I'm looking for the following:

`get_post_ID_by_title('My post title', 'customposttype');`

What should I be doing?

Comment: How were you using `get_page_by_title` and is the custom post type hierarchal, i don't think `get_page`(called by `get_page_by_title`) will work for non-hierarchal types.

Comment: Yes, the custom post type in question is non-hierachal.

Comment: Ignore previous comment regarding being hierarchal, that shouldn't matter, how were you calling `get_page_by_title`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** As of WordPress 3.0 you can use the *built-in* function [`get_page_by_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) with the third parameter `$post_type`:

```
$post = get_page_by_title( 'Post Title', OBJECT, 'post_type' );

$post_id = $post ? $post->ID : 0;
```

---

**Original Answer**

you can use this function that jumps by google "get post by title"

```
/**
* Retrieve a post given its title.
*
* @uses $wpdb
*
* @param string $post_title Page title
* @param string $post_type post type ('post','page','any custom type')
* @param string $output Optional. Output type. OBJECT, ARRAY_N, or ARRAY_A.
* @return mixed
*/
function get_post_by_title($page_title, $post_type ='post' , $output = OBJECT) {
    global $wpdb;
        $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", $page_title, $post_type));
        if ( $post )
            return get_post($post, $output);
 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So far I've managed to avoid using DB queries, as I prefer to use standard WP functions. Is this really the only way to achieve what I need?

Comment: The code posted is pretty much a direct copy of the `get_page_by_title` [function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3162), the major difference here is that it'll work for non-hierarchal types, so it's one worth having in your function collection.

Comment: @t31os I never said it was mine i only added the $post_type paean to it and yep its going to my collection.

Comment: I wasn't accusing you of anything mate, if anything i'm supporting your answer.. ;) You already got my +1.. :)

Comment: @t31os I know ,its just a bad joke :)

Comment: How is this different from native `get_page_by_title()`?.. `get_page()` is pretty much alias of `get_post()` I don't see how change impact anything.

Comment: @Rarst Now that you pointed that out it is the same, i can't see the difference.

Comment: @t31os so where does _non-hierarchical_ thing you mentioned comes into play if function is essentially same?..

Comment: Don't know what i was thinking this morning, get_page calls get_post anyway, and i have no clue why i thought get_page only works for hierarchal types, i don't think that's true as it happens.

Comment: This can be done easily with the page object. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a function parameter. Throw a null in for the second optional paramter $output and this function should work for you.

```
get_page_by_title('My post title', null, 'customposttype');
```

I just ran into the same issue and adding the null fixed it for me.

Comment: That `null` should really be `OBJECT` for clarity. But, yes he was essentially throwing the post type in as the output type by leaving out the output type.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to shy away from direct DB queries.  Instead, I use the `WP_Query` object to parse things for me.

This is, basically, a function I use in one of my themes to get a post based on a given slug:

```
function get_post_id( $slug, $post_type ) {
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'name' => $slug,
            'post_type' => $post_type
        )
    );

    $query->the_post();

    return get_the_ID();
}
```

This will create a query using the WP API to fetch a post of a specific type with a given slug, will run the regular loop functions on the result, and return the ID of the post.  You could also use it to return the entire post by modifying the function a bit, but that's up to you.

Comment: Instead of `$query->the_post()` which alters the loop and will disrupt any `get_the_xxx` functions after it, rather use: 

    if ($query->have_posts())
     {
      return $query->posts[0]->ID;
     }
     else
     {
      return 0;
     }

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old now, but it still pops up when searching for this on Google. So, here's a simple way to do it:

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'my post title' );
```

or

```
$page = get_post_ID_by_title('my post title', OBJECT, 'customposttype');
```

Then just use the $page object to grab the ID:

```
$page->ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently (WP >4.9.2) you'll find your "any" given post/page etc. by title/slug this way:

```
$page = get_posts(
    array(
        //'name'      => 'your-post-slug', // by post slug
        'title'      => 'Your post title', // by post title
        'post_type' => 'page' // post type of your preference
    )
);

if ($page = $page[0]) // First/lowest ID taken if many objects
{
    // Then you do whatever is needed...
    // $id = $page->id;
    // $content = $page->post_content;
    // or $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
    // etc.
}
```