# Query specific posts from parent by slug rather ID

Tags: query-posts, slug, id

I'm developing a theme in a local machine and migrating it to a production server. To keep things in sync, i'm trying to avoid any queries of specific ID's

On the homepage, i'm trying to query the top 3 pages (by menu_order) from a parent page (NOT the homepage). It works perfectly with the hardcoded ID, but i'm stumped trying to figure out a way to do this without the ID. Seems like I should be able to use the slug, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code i'm working with:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'post_parent' => '74',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
);
query_posts($args);
```

So rather than 'post_parent' => '74' I want to use the page slug (e.g. 'books'). Any ideas?

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11292/how-do-i-get-a-post-page-or-cpt-id-from-a-title-or-slug) seems promising, but as others commented, I'd also like to avoid direct DB queries and the second suggestion didn't work working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two WordPress functions you could try:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

(as suggested by @t31os in the comments to your quoted link)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

if you have already tried them, please describe how these failed to do what you want.

Comment: $ Thanks Michael. I don't know why I couldn't find get_page_by_title.